# Columns datatypes inconsistency

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is the case:
There are lot of columns in my databases inside one sqlserver that contains the same data but there is a big inconsistency in datatypes lenght for them.
For example I have column called "name" in schemas stage and dbo in DB1 and the same column in DB2. In all those places this column has different lenght of data type:

- stage.name is defined as varchar(10),
- dbo.name is defined as varchar(20),
- column "name" in DB2 is defined as varchar(max)

Is there any tool that can help me to fix that?
I mean different that writing SQL queries agains Information_schema.columns and then genereting manually alter scripts to implement changes.

Comment: Your search skills need enhancement. Use the meta-data (e.g., sys.columns) to compare  the datatypes of columns that share a name between tables like [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2779/ways-to-compare-and-find-differences-for-sql-server-tables-and-data/). As Martin notes - you will need to write logic to associate <this table name> with <that table name> - which might be a problem.

Comment: And note that using names like "DB2" can be very confusing since DB2 is the name of an actual database engine from IBM.

Answer (score 0):

As they are in different schemas and even in a different database, do you know for sure that they actually represent the same piece of information? A generic term like name could mean many things in different contexts - e.g. Australian State Names have a very specific max size that I can define, but a City Name could vary hugely. Don't change anything without understanding the actual domain of the data and then ensure the size is appropriate.